# what is the proper way to do unsigned parameter in mysql stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a procedure to delete a user information from all the tables in our database.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `unrollme_version3`.`del_user` (in v_user_id int(10))
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION; 
    DELETE FROM user_table1 WHERE `user_id` = v_user_id;
    DELETE FROM user_table2 WHERE `user_id` = v_user_id;
    DELETE FROM user_table3 WHERE `user_id` = v_user_id;
COMMIT;
END
```

i would like to in someway make the input variable only unsigned to match how the structure of the database is setup. is this possible and what is the best practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add the word `unsigned`. I removed the `(10)` just because it's irrelevant. It just describes how much digits shall be shown, but it's always an int with 4 bytes.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `unrollme_version3`.`del_user` (in v_user_id int unsigned)
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION; 
    DELETE FROM user_table1 WHERE `user_id` = v_user_id;
    DELETE FROM user_table2 WHERE `user_id` = v_user_id;
    DELETE FROM user_table3 WHERE `user_id` = v_user_id;
COMMIT;
END
```

You can force to throw an error instead of a warning by doing

```
SET sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES';
```

For more information see the [manual.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html)

Comment: i tried making that change and it works partially as i hoped it throws a warning but not an error preventing it from attempting it.

Comment: ok not something im going to opt into setting at the moment until i have a better understanding  of the sql_mode but thanks for that added bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in your code for v_user_id as negative and return an error instead.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `unrollme_version3`.`del_user` (in v_user_id int(10))
BEGIN
if v_user_id < 0 then
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid user_id passed';
end if;
START TRANSACTION; 
    DELETE FROM user_table1 WHERE `user_id` = v_user_id;
    DELETE FROM user_table2 WHERE `user_id` = v_user_id;
    DELETE FROM user_table3 WHERE `user_id` = v_user_id;
COMMIT;
END
```

Edited out the unsigned part. The above is just plain SQL to do a raiserror or signal when out of range data is provided.

Comment: Have a look at your link and see for yourself, that there is an unsigned version of each.

Comment: yes the second row for each in that table is the values if it is unsigned.